# information regarding .idl files in cpp

Tags: c++, webkit, idl

I am working on webkit(webkit.org), an open source code browser.

While looking the webcore code i find there there are some `.idl` files and these idl looks different then normal cpp/c code.

I want to understand the use of `.idl` files and how they are useful.

Answer (score 1):

IDL means Interface Definition Language. It is part of RPC (Remote Procedure Call). Search for RPC. There are tons on info on this topic..

Answer (score 0):

WebKit IDL files are used to generate bindings, for JavaScript, Objective-C, and COM, so programs using WebKit can get at the DOM from those languages.

For example, the JavaScript bindings expose DOM to scripts in web pages, while the Objective-C bindings exposed DOM to programs on Mac OS X.

You can find details of what are WebKit IDLs and how to use in [this link](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebKitIDL).